# valueChanges observable seems to be subscribing to data before subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a reactive form which is dynamically created. I get data from a service in the form of an observable (that comes from a Subject), and want to subscribe to the form's `valueChanges` after it's created. When I first set it up, I subscribed to each of the service's observables and to valueChanges, but I saw data from every step of the form's creation, which makes sense, as the two service observables could emit after.

So I refactored the setup to use `Observable.zip`, which as far as I can understand, makes the code linear, so the form should be setup before I get to my `valueChanges` subscription, but I still see every step of the form creation happening.

```
this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'search': '',
    'types': this.formBuilder.group({}),
    'dates': this.formBuilder.array([]),
});

let formData = Observable.zip(
    this.eventService.getTypes(),
    this.eventService.getDates()
);
formData.forEach(data => {
    let types = data[0],
        dates = data[1];
    types.forEach(type => {
        this.types.push(type);
        (<FormGroup>(this.filterForm.get('types'))).addControl(type, new FormControl())
    });
    dates.forEach(date => {
        this.dates.push(date.format('dddd'));
        (<FormArray>(this.filterForm.get('dates'))).push(new FormControl(false))
    });
    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
});
```

When I say I see the values as the form is building, I mean this:

```
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(0)}
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(1)}
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(2)}
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(3)}
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(4)}
{search: "", types: {…}, dates: Array(5)}
```

There are a dozen entries before it as the types field builds.

Is this how this should be working? My goal is to subscribe AFTER the form is built, so I only get the values when the form is changed by the user.

Comment: You could try subscribing during the `afterViewInit` lifecycle

Comment: Why `afterViewInit`? This doesn't yet have anything to do with the view; shouldn't the subscription not give me values before I subscribe?

Comment: You're running the subscription on the same level as the `formBuilder`. This means you're subscribed to the filterForm while it's being initialized, and likely before it's finished being built out (and therefore the value of the subscription will be empty to start). Since the form being build is part of building the view, you should be safe to subscribe after the view is initialized. Hope this helps!

Comment: I take this means the form isn't built as soon as I hit a method like `addControl`? Because the only way this makes sense is if the form builds async, allowing the subscribe to come before the form initializes. I'll move the code to get it working, but I still don't really understand why it's behaving as it is :/

Comment: Correct, it's all async

Comment: Ok, then this all makes a lot more sense. Annoying, but makes more sense.

Comment: Did this work for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little different suggestion. In RxJS apart from the `subscribe()` method that subscribes to the chain there are also `toPromise()` and `forEach()` that internally subscribe as well. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L223

And I think that's what's happening to you. The `forEach` method subscribes to the `formData` Observable and invokes its callback for every value emitted. But you're also using `this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe` inside the callback which means you're creating a new subscription every time `formData` emits a value.

I don't know what your code should do but I think you could restructure it to something like the following:

```
Observable.zip(
    this.eventService.getTypes(),
    this.eventService.getDates()
  )
  .do(data => {
    let types = data[0],
        dates = data[1];
    types.forEach(type => {
        this.types.push(type);
        (<FormGroup>(this.filterForm.get('types'))).addControl(type, new FormControl())
    });
    dates.forEach(date => {
        this.dates.push(date.format('dddd'));
        (<FormArray>(this.filterForm.get('dates'))).push(new FormControl(false))
    });
  })
  .switchMap(() => this.filterForm.valueChanges))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I really like this idea, but according to VSCode, `do` doesn't exist on the return from zip? Only `dowhile`.

Comment: In RxJS 5.4 you need to import it with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'` or in RxJS 5.5 it was renamed to `tap`.

Comment: `tap` was renamed for the lettable version, but the fluent version of `do` still exists. [rxjs/src/add/operator/do.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c3c56867eaf93f302ac7cd588034c7d8712f2834/src/add/operator/do.ts)

Comment: Strangely, it didn't let me import do as you recommended, but piping through tap seems to have solved the problem. Concerned that the `zip` and `forEach` were causing the problems, as mentioned in the answer, I tried the solution with `forkJoin`, and got the same issue. Still not sure I understand what's happening, and that bothers me, but it works now I guess :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't subscribe in the OnInit lifecycle hook. Create a method that handles the subscription and call that method after declaring the form model in OnInit.

More generally though you can skip a specific number of emissions using the skip() operator, or use filter/mapping to only process emits after a specific condition / structure has been met.

Comment: Even if I move the subscription to a different method, which does make sense, doesn't it have the same effect as the code above? If it's synchronous, it'll still trigger at that time. I guess I'm confused why the subscription, which is after the form is built, is showing me the stages of the form being built.

Comment: What specifically is being emitted when you say "stages of the form being built"

Comment: I added the console output to the question.